# How to solve for $H$ in the equation $A = \frac{H^{P+1}-H}{H-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you re-express this equation to solve for $H$?  All other variables are known:

$$A = \frac{H^{P+1}-H}{H-1}$$

My first request here and my maths isn't good enough to tell me whether it's possible or not...I really hope it is!

Comment: can you tell us please for what the variables are standing?

Comment: It seems unlikely. Here's an alternative expression (as long as $H\neq 1$):

$$\begin{align*}
A & = \frac{H^{p+1}-H}{H-1}\\
&=\frac{H(H^p-1)}{H-1}\\
&=\frac{H(H-1)(H^{p-1}+H^{p-2}+\cdots+H+1)}{H-1}\\
&=H\cdot (H^{p-1}+H^{p-2}+\cdots+H+1)\\
&=H^p+H^{p-1}+\cdots+H^2+H
\end{align*}$$

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: any information on size of H, or any other relevant details? As it stands, no